# Ubuntu 14.04 Nvidia Configuration file Location for editing refresh rate manually

Tags: nvidia

Hello I am having a hard time to find .conf file for Nvidia Drivers.
System is working fine with accelleration but I need to make some adjustments manually but I cant find it anywhere.

Normally it is in:

```
 /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

or

```
 /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

But I cant find it anywhere.

My hardware:

Lenovo Y510P with 2 X nVidia 755M SLI

Just to mention if it helps, this laptop is Optimus enabled but switching on Ubuntu works only when I have second graphic card removed from Ultrabay. So normally when I boot with two GPUs it detects just those 2 nvdia graphics card and integrated Intel Graphic is disabled by BIOS.

I dont care about SLI as I know that SLI dont work very well under Linux with Nvidia propietary drivers(jet), and especially dont work on mobile GPUs.

Generating new config file using

```
nvidia-xconfig
```

will render my setup unbootable and since my setup is working fine there is no point generating new config file but as I said I cant find current config file anywhere.

**Edit:**

I tried nvidia-xconfig again and it seemed to be that previous file have been messed up because it works now even with newly generated xorg.conf.

Here is [Xorg.0.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a769wqaq46v0vgt/Xorg.0.log?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is not present when X server uses autoconfiguration but it should be possible to create a new one. It may be that `nvidia-xconfig` selects different GPU than the autoconfiguration. You can check which GPU is the X server using in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and compare it with `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` generated by `nvidia-xconfig`.

Also, if your adjustments are regarding the GPU, you can set a lot of that in `nvidia-settings` without the need for `xorg.conf`.

Comment: I have uploaded Xorg.0.log. I cant find out which GPU is XServer using. I understand that I can use nvidia-settings to make some adjustments but what I need is to adjust Refresh rate. For example on windows I can manually set custom refresh rate in nvidia panel but in Linux this option is not available. I understand that I wont notice any difference after 60Hz but I need to adjust it manually for testing purposes.

Comment: It uses PCI:1:0:0. The other card is PCI:7:0:0.

Comment: Right so is there any way to change refresh rate manually like it used to be in xorg.conf? If it is autoconfigured, where is configuration file stored?

Comment: It still autoconfigurates everything that is not set in `xorg.conf`. Just by default, there is no fixed configuration and therefore no `xorg.conf`.

Comment: OK, I understand now. I thought that it autoconfigure itself once and stores config somewhere but now I understand what you mean. I guess that I wont be able to change refresh rate. If you have any suggestions I will appreciate that. Otherwise thanks for your help.

Comment: Good one!  Upvoted!  ;-)