# Ubuntu 17.04 and AMD Radeon R5 340X and Intel HD Graphics 4600

Tags: radeon, amd-graphics

I had problems after install Ubuntu 17.04 several times, I think the problem is related to my 4 monitors and two video-cards: AMD Radeon R5 340X and Intel HD Graphics 4600.

I don't know why; during the initialization, two of them try to initialize but I realize one driver (I don't know which of them) does not initialize correctly, in such a way that the monitor's led blinks orange, like when there is no signal. After trying turning on the computer several times, suddenly all my 4 monitors worked fine!.

Is there a way to "save permanently" my "working fine" configuration? [Here is my logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7_vYfVpkV8_cHpnUmtQNW5PN0U).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you change any settings to make the display configuration work? If it just works intermittently there's no way to "save" that state. Instead one would need to investigate what makes the set-up work only sometimes.

Comment: Thanks. What would you do to investigate?

Comment: There's a segmentation fault in X.org. Looks like a bug to me that you should report (unless fixed upstream). Did you install any graphics driver(s)? Can you boot successfully with only one screen?

Comment: Yes I've installed the graphics driver from manufacturer (AMD) but it didn't work. During the boot Ubuntu stay in a eternal black screen with no messages immediately after grub initialization. All screens stay dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything related to my Monitors is in ~/.config/monitors.xml. Backing up this file and Storing it in a secure location should do the trick. As mentioned in the comments though, if you have intermittent problems saving a incorrect config isn't going to fix anything.

Comment: Thanks. But about the video card configuration, do you know what files I need to back it up?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/585519/ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-configuration-file-location-for-editing-refresh-rate-manuall